# Modifying appearance of number for \part command

Tags: parts

Under the default usage of the `\part` command, the text appears on a new page as "Part I" then on a new line "This is the name of the part".

I am trying to change the appearance of the "Part I" text. I have figured out how to remove the "Part" text using

```
\renewcommand{\partname}{}
```

I wish to also change the font size and color of the "I" text, but I am stuck. Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: The code of `\part` (actually `\@part`) depends on the underlying class. You should provide at least a compilable document

Comment: @ChristianHupfer the document is based on the book class, actually in a class called "Dissertate.cls" - there are a bunch of files required for compiling the document so I unfortunately wouldn't be able to recreate it here. Is there a way to do it for the book class? Perhaps I could go from there.

Comment: I provided an answer to your question which is pretty much doing what you requested. Please give feedback

Answer (score 4):

The `\@part` macro is the one that must be changed here if numbered `\parts` are under consideration.

The `\partname\nobreakspace\thepart` construct is used in `\@part` in the `book.cls` (and in `report` as well)

A patch with `\xpatchcmd` can be applied in order to strip the `\partname\nobreakspace` content and use `\textcolor{partnumbercolour}{\thepart}` instead only.

Redefinition of `\partname` may break other features, I don't recommend it here.

Since the user class is loading `book` only, `\AtBeginDocument{...}` might be necessary to make the change effective.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xcolor}


\usepackage{xpatch}

\colorlet{partnumbercolour}{blue}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{
\xpatchcmd{\@part}{\partname\nobreakspace\thepart}{\textcolor{partnumbercolour}{\thepart}}{}{}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\part{Foo}

\part{Foobar}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Clearly a German document: not a single inter-word space in the whole thing:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Wheredoyouwanttohaveinterwordspace? ;-)